# How to quote a list from a paper?

Tags: writing, quotations, lists

I'm writing a paper and I need to quote the following list:

1. Step1: Compute the center of each triangle and the correspondences between the center and three vertexes of the
   triangle;
2. Step2: Set up the Kd-tree according the centers of triangles;
3. Step3: Search the Kd-tree and check up the topological connectivity of the corresponding edges, and find the
   boundary edges;
4. Step4: Distinguish the different boundary loops according to the topological connectivity of vertexes;

Do I quote like the following?

"

1. Step1: Compute the center of each triangle and the correspondences between the center and three vertexes of the
   triangle;
2. Step2: Set up the Kd-tree according the centers of triangles;
3. Step3: Search the Kd-tree and check up the topological connectivity of the corresponding edges, and find the
   boundary edges;
4. Step4: Distinguish the different boundary loops according to the topological connectivity of vertexes;
   "(place citation number here)

Answer (score 2):

If you must quote 'inline', paragraph by paragraph, it’s usual to put a left-quote (single or double) at the beginning of *each* paragraph, but put your right-quote (closing quote) *only at the end of the entire quotation*, thus:

“1. Step1: Compute the center of each triangle and the correspondences between the center and three vertexes of the
triangle;

“2. Step2: Set up the Kd-tree according the centers of triangles;

“3. Step3: Search the Kd-tree and check up the topological connectivity of the corresponding edges, and find the
boundary edges;

“4. Step4: Distinguish the different boundary loops according to the topological connectivity of vertexes.”

(Your publisher will determine whether the paragraphs are spaced or first-line-indented, and whether the initial numerals 'hang'.)

For a quote this long, however, it’s much better to indent the entire passage, which permits you to omit the quotation marks altogether:

> > 1. Step1: Compute the center of each triangle and the correspondences between the center and three vertexes of the
> >        triangle;
> > 2. Step2: Set up the Kd-tree according the centers of triangles;
> > 3. Step3: Search the Kd-tree and check up the topological connectivity of the corresponding edges, and find the
> >        boundary edges;
> > 4. Step4: Distinguish the different boundary loops according to the topological connectivity of vertexes.

In either case, put the citation information wherever your particular discipline or journal requires. And in fact, what I have described here is only the most usual practise; you must be guided by the prescriptions of whatever style guide or house manual your instructor or publisher prefers.

Comment: There are better chances on writersSE.